# How to make a REST call in module file with Angular

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo, angular-httpclient, refresh-token

Is it possible to do a REST call in the `x.module.ts` file?

I created a GraphQLModule to work with Apollo Client and also this library that helps refreshing tokens [apollo-link-token-refresh](https://github.com/newsiberian/apollo-link-token-refresh)

But the implementation keeps failing when making the `POST` call to the server. I tried injecting the `HttpClient` into the function without success

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ApolloModule, Apollo, APOLLO_OPTIONS } from 'apollo-angular';
import { HttpLinkModule, HttpLink } from 'apollo-angular-link-http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { InMemoryCache, IntrospectionFragmentMatcher} from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { ApolloLink, from } from 'apollo-link';
import { onError } from 'apollo-link-error';
import { TokenRefreshLink } from 'apollo-link-token-refresh';
import * as jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

const uri = 'http://localhost:4000/graphql';

export function provideApollo(httpLink: HttpLink, httpClient: HttpClient) {

  ...

  const refreshLink = new TokenRefreshLink({
    accessTokenField: 'accessToken',
    isTokenValidOrUndefined: () => {
      const token = getAccessToken();
      if (!token) {
        return true;
      }

      try {
        const { exp } = jwt_decode(token);
        if (Date.now() > exp * 1000) {
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        return false;
      }
    },
    fetchAccessToken: () => {
      return httpClient
        .post(uri, {}, { withCredentials: true })
        .toPromise() as Promise<any>;
    },
    handleFetch: (accessToken: string) => {
      setAccessToken(accessToken);
    },
    handleError: (err: Error) => {
      console.warn('Your refresh token is invalid. Try to relogin');
    },
  }) as any;

  ...

  return {
    link: from([authMiddleware, logoutLink, refreshLink, http]),
    cache
  };
}

@NgModule({
  exports: [ApolloModule, HttpLinkModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
      useFactory: provideApollo,
      deps: [HttpLink],
    },
  ],
})
export class GraphQLModule {}
```

I couldn't find any examples trying to make calls from the module definition file. I guess I could try installing libraries like `axios` but are there any native solution or workarounds to this in Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `HttpClient` inside the deps array, so Angular could inject it

```
 providers: [
    {
      provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
      useFactory: provideApollo,
      deps: [HttpLink,HttpClient],// HttpClient added
    },
  ],
```

Comment: thanks, I just tried your implementation. I did this in the constructor `constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient)` but I am getting `Cannot read property 'httpClient' of undefined`

Comment: can you post your body inside the constructor?

Comment: yeah, just updated the answer. I moved the `provideApollo` function into the class but now I'm getting `Cannot find name 'provideApollo'.`

Comment: oh, sorry my mistake, you are using this function inside apollo configuration, just undo everything and add HttpClient inside deps array,    deps: [HttpLink,HttpClient], and then use it inside provideApollo(httpLink: HttpLink, httpClient: HttpClient)... check if it works and I'll update the answer